# Objective-C way or compiler directive to force a class file include a method without adding a protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom singleton MyColors class to easily change colors of some buttons easily in many `UIViewController`s at the same time.

I put `#import "MyColors.h"` in every class I need to get color of a button.

Everything works perfectly and setting a the color value in `MyColors`, that color is applied correctly to where I want.

Now, I want to change colors alive. So I send a `NSNotification` with name `"COLORS_CHANGED"`.

So every class will observe that and apply colors immediately.

**What I want to do is:**

Force XCode to remind me that the `.m`file that includes `MyColors.h` must also include `colorsChanged` method for observing. So, this will prevent me forgetting to add observer

**OR:**

Add something like a `Category` or something like that into `MyColors.h` to do this kind of thing...

**What I don't want to do:**

I don't want to create a protocol and add it as delegate to header files of every `.m`file that includes `MyColors.h`. Because I can forget that too.. If not, this would be the way ofcourse...

So, I am trying to find an Objective-C way to do this, or a compiler way that works with XCode to do this.

Thank you for sharing your ideas.

**Update**: I use color values for anything that needs colors not just buttons.

Comment: One way would be to subclass `UIViewController` and use it as a base class for your view-controllers.

Comment: you may include MyColors.h into your precompiled header file...

Comment: Since your color is only used for button, you can subclass the UIButton classe and listen to the notification to change the color button.

Comment: @bsarr007 My bad, It is used for anything that uses color; I am updating the question to reflect this information.

Comment: Could you provide some code, how you respond on `COLOR_CHANGED` notification.

Comment: If this is a mechanism to remind you then I'm not sure there is any solid solution.  You say you don't want to use a `@protocol` but this looks like something a protocol is designed to address. However Xcode cannot force you to declare that your class *conforms* to the protocol.  I don't believe there is a satisfactory answer that meets  your current requirements, therefore those requirements will have to change.

Comment: @trojanfoe not XCode but maybe a compiler flag or directive? For example, we can make a class ignore warnings for deprecated sdk methods by supplying a compiler directive with `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`.

Comment: @Cy-4AH `[myButton setTitleColor:[[MyColor instance] colorFor:@"buttonType1"]]; self.view.backgroundColor = [[MyColor instance] colorFor:@"backgroundType1"]];`

Comment: I don't believe so.  If I wanted to do this then I would write a python script to trawl my header files and perform the check there.  This could then be configured as project target and made to be a dependency of the app target.  (I have done this in the past with a C++ project to ensure that no *non-thread-safe* library functions were being called).

Comment: @trojanfoe Would you please direct me to some reference document to do something similar to this? (though with large file base, it may be slow)

Comment: Well you simply create a new target in Xcode and tell it to run whatever script you like.  You don't have to do it in Python; that just happens to be my favourite scripting language.  I don't have any reference other than Apple's Xcode guides.

Comment: @frankish Is it only subclassses of `UIView` or `UIViewController` that need to listen for color changes?

Answer (score 0):

implement this functionality in a base class and make all your UIViewController-s inherit it. i.e - in the base class register for this notification and change the common objects' colors and also call there a virtual method for the inheritors to change their extra objects' colors.

Good luck,